# onclick of lable get checkbox value inside

Tags: css, angularjs, checkbox, onclick

I have checkbox insde label and for design purpose I add div there. My requirment is to get checkbox value onclick event of label, now I am getting false for all time checkbox clicked event

```
<label class="text-xs col-xs-4 switch">
  <input type="checkbox" ng-model="inAtlas"> 
  <div class="slider round"></div>                                  
</label>
```

I want to get `$scope.inAtlas` value on click of `label`. Currently getting false for all click event.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a demo - please note that:

1. When you use `label` to toggle a radio button / checkbox don't forget to link the `label` to the `input` using `id` and `for`.
2. Initialize the value of `inAtlas` with false (or true as is required) or you will get `undefined` till you toggle the checkbox for the first time.

```js
var app = angular.module("test", []); 
app.controller("test", function($scope){
  $scope.inAtlas = false; /*better to do this - or undefined till you toggle the checkbox*/
  $scope.getValue = function(){
    console.log($scope.inAtlas);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body ng-app="test" ng-controller="test">
  <label class="text-xs col-xs-4 switch" for="check-box">
    <input type="checkbox" ng-model="inAtlas" id="check-box">
    <span class="slider round">Toggle me</span>
  </label>
  <br><br>
  <button ng-click="getValue()">Get checkbox value</button>
</body>
```

Let me know if you have any more queries, thanks!

Comment: I tried with this.. but it shows false even after click on the span

Comment: @KaviSuja how come? check the snippet above - maybe you are not implementing it right... could you please check again?

Comment: ya ok I will check